# How do I check specific data when reading in data from a remote source with kendo.data.datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile, kendo-datasource

I am using Telerik Platform to build a hybrid news app. I am pulling in data remotely and I have everything working correctly, but now I need to check to see for featured stories and move them into an variable. I have the data pulling into like this:

```
viewModel = new kendo.observable({
            newsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: serviceURL,
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "posts"
                }
            }) 
});
```

When the json is pulled it looks like this when I console.log(viewModel):

```
ht.exend.init
    _aggregate:
    _changeHandler:
    _data: ht.extend.init[25]
        0: ht.extend.init    //Each article
            article_date: "June 09, 2015"
            author: "James Dean"
            categories: ht.extend.init[1]
                0: ht.extend.init
                    id: 1
                    title: "OC"
                length: 1
            content: "<p>Content</p>"
            custom_fields: ht.extend.init
                Views:
                featured_post: ht.extend.init[1]
                    0: "0"     //0 if not featured, 1 if featured
                    length: 1
                parent: function (){return i}
            date: "2015-06-09"
            .
            .
            .
            url: "url"
        1: ht.extend.init
        2: ht.extend.init
        .
        .
        .
        25: ht.extend.init
    _destroyed: Array[0]
    .
    .
    .
    transport: ft.extend.init
```

What I would like to do is have it check each article to see if it is a featured post (ie have the value of 1) and move it to an array of var featured = []. 
I cannot find anything in the telerik documentation, and I have tried to put success: function () {} in the call for the dataSource but that doesn't work either. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get access to your json data within the datasource.  I'm using the [requestEnd](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestEnd) event.  You didn't explain exactly what you're trying to do with the data once you know an article is featured so I'm just showing a basic way to get the data and work with it after it's retrieved.

```
viewModel = new kendo.observable({
        newsItems: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: serviceURL,
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "posts"
            },
                requestEnd: function (e) {
                    var response = e.response;
                    var type = e.type;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    //now use obj to access your json data
                    //The if statement is just an example, you will need to
                    //change it to fit your data model 
                    if ( obj.featured_post == 1 ) {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
        }) 
});
```

Comment: When I tried that it said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: Your serviceURL needs to be returning valid JSON.

Comment: I ended up using this to get the featured_post variable e.response.posts[j].custom_fields.fearless_featured_post[0];  (inside of a for loop j < 25)